# Programming related documents editor

Tags: documentation, editor

Is there a document editor that helps formatting documents like API documents or specifications?
I prefer not to use Word but something that is more productive.

Answer (score 2):

[LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) is particularly well-suited to technical documents, I find.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you use, specially for API documentations, I'd use XML comments and then use a program like [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) and [SHFB](http://shfb.codeplex.com/).

Comment: But what if there is no code yet?

Comment: I have to admit that's the first time I even hear anything remotely close to writing documentation BEFORE code.

Comment: I'm submitting this to an open source project for their review. They want to see the API before they decide if it's in. It's a matter of flexability